# PHP Delete Form Not Deleting With no Errors

Tags: php

The form is supposed to delete a customer row from the customer table by entering customer ID, but it is not doing what it is supposed to, I dont know why! When I executed the PHP file I dont get any errors.

I know it should work because I used the same code to delete information from the employee table and it worked fine.

Delete Customer Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
    <?php include 'project_header.php'; ?>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  </head>

    <body>
    <form action="customer_delete.php" method="post">
        <h2> Delete a Customer</h2>
        <p>Please Enter Customer Information:</p>
            Customer ID: <input type="text" ID="Customer_ID"/><br>    
        <input type="submit" value= "Delete"/><input type="reset"/>
        </form>
    </body>

 <?php include 'project_footer.php'; ?>
   </html>
```

Delete Customer PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include 'project_header.php'; ?>
<body>
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'display.php';

#form data
$Customer_ID=$_POST['Customer_ID'];

$sql = "delete from CUSTOMERS where Customer_ID = :Customer_ID;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

# data stored in an associative array
$data = array( 'Customer_ID' => $Customer_ID);

if($stmt->execute($data)){
                $rows_affected = $stmt->rowCount();
                echo "<h2>".$rows_affected." row deleted sucessfully!</h2>";
                display("select Customer_ID as Customer ID FROM CUSTOMERS;");
}
else
{
        echo "\nPDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
?>
</body>
<?php include 'project_footer.php'; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: in delete customer php, in line $sql, plz check whether where Customer_ID = :Customer_ID;"; is right or not ...? where Customer_ID = '$Customer_ID'"; and name attribute is imp in input..... name is the name that is used when the value is passed (in the url or in the posted data). id is used to uniquely identify the element for CSS styling and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no `name` attribute on your text box. This is how PHP gets the `POST` information, so without it being set, you can't access what the user inputted. Simply change the attribute from `ID` to `name`(or just add the `name` attribute if `id` is needed) and that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Customer ID: <input type="text" ID="Customer_ID"/>
```

In this line you need to add the "name" attribute, and that should fix the issue.

What you should do is:

```
Customer ID: <input type="text" ID="Customer_ID" name="Customer_ID"/>
```

Greetings!